# How to connect flask server with OPC python script

Tags: python, flask, server

I would like to create a Flask Python server to serve for a Mobile App / Web server as visualization for Data from PLC. I do not know how to connect Flask Server with another script and to exchange Data between it in full duplex. Is it possible to do it over Sqlite ? Can I write / read a data to the same DB from 2 scripts / servers ? I draw some explanation of my problem (first picture is a problem and a second one may be the possible solution ?/ thanks in advance for your experienced suggestions)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHZpb.jpg)

Comment: See the link for a picture description of my problem

Comment: is there a reason you can't just import that script into your flask-application and run it from there?

Comment: No there is no reason. But I do not know how to implement it in Flask. Over thread?. 
I would have more PLCs, therefore I have to read / write Data to more than 1 PLC over OPC Script in python and I did not want to make Flask server slower. Or do you think it will not impact the speed of Flask server?

Comment: It depends of course what your script does, but if you use threads you shouldn't be much slower than using anything else because if i got you right it runs on the same machine anyway.

Comment: ok Thanks, it means I will exchange the data between these two codes (threading) over MySQL DB ? Is it a good solution, or should I be aware of something? Thanks once more in advance for your contribution

Comment: I actually ment why your flask server and your opc script can't be the same application.

Comment: You are right, I could call this script over a Flask request from Mobile / Web Server, Thanks mate for Idee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create apis in flask and use [requests module](https://2.python-requests.org//en/v0.10.6/) from another script and consume the apis that are built on Flask.

Comment: which apis do you mind? Should I implement processing / requesting of methods in my OPC Server script? The same thing what Flask is doing on the Flask server what I already got?